# How to correct date format while export from Postico to CSV and open on Excel?

Tags: excel, postgresql, csv, export, postico

I'm exporting my query result from Postico [a PostgreSQL client](https://eggerapps.at/postico/).

This is how it looks like after running query on Postico 
[- my query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQCSF.png)

And when I export it to CSV and open with Excel, it becomes like this 
[- my excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdDzZ.png)

It went from "**2018-09-17**" to "**17M09M18**". I use UTF-8 as encoding type while exporting.

I'm using macOS, Postico 1.4.2 and Excel 2016.

I don't really know what's wrong. I suspect that it has something to do with Mac system but I can't figure it out.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: What does it look like if you just open the csv with notepad?

Comment: The same text "**17M09M18**".